Transitive Group Actions and Non-Trivial Element Existence
Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $A$. The action is said to be transitive if for every $a, b \in A$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $ga = b$. Prove that if $|A| > 1$ and the action is transitive, then there exists $g \in G$ such that $ga \neq a$ for every $a \in A$.
My attempt:
By way of contradiction, suppose that for every $g \in G$, it holds that $ga = a$, which would be the trivial action, and thus the transitive action does not hold, leading to a contradiction.
My question is this correct?

No.  Transitive just means that, given $a,b\in A$,  we can find some element $g_1\in G$ such that $g_1a=b$.  Doesn't mean there can't be another element which fixes $a$.  Nor does it mean that $g_1$ can't fix some elements of $A$.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

The negation of "there exists $g\in G$ such that for all $a\in A$, $ga\neq A$" is not "for every $g\in G$ for every $a\in A$, $ga=a$". The negation is "for each $g\in G$ there exists at least one $a\in A$ such that $ga=a$."

Arturo's right.  You messed up your quantifiers, so to speak.  So is Lulu (I think).  I'd type an answer but sounds like this might be marked as a dupe. Nah, maybe I will anyway.

Hint:  see Burnside's lemma.

The correct contradictory assumption is:
$$\forall g\in G, \exists a\in A\mid ga=a$$
This means that $\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|\ge1$ for every $g\in G$. Therefore:
$$\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=\left|\operatorname{Fix}(e)\right|+\sum_{g\in G\setminus\{e\}}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|\ge |A|+|G|-1$$
and hence (Burnside's counting lemma):
$$\text{ number of orbits}\ge1+\frac{|A|-1}{|G|}>1$$
because $|A|>1$: contradiction.

It happens you are incorrect.
As we know the group action gives us a homomorphism from $G$ into $S_A.$  The latter is the group of permutations of the set $A.$
In this parlance, the element $g$ we are looking for corresponds to a permutation   is a derangement.   It moves everything,  or has no fixed point.
I'll try to help you prove it if you get stuck.
